# How to remove items from a dynamic list in Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

There are use cases, such as the [expense tracker app](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/qs_aotp_app_step2_cmp.htm) in the *Lightning Components Developer's Guide*, where users are entering data into a dynamic list that grows with each user input submission. My question is, in these situations, what is the most efficient way to implement a UI element that allows the user to *remove* an item from the list?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Luckily the **aura:iteration** component has a super convenient, built-in attribute called **indexVar**. By leveraging indexVar I am able to pass the array index to the controller action, which can then use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove an element from the list.

For example, consider the following aura:iteration element:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.leads}" var="lead" indexVar="i">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ui:button label="Remove" press="{!c.handleRemoveLeadButtonClick}">
                <span data-index="{!i}"></span>
            </ui:button>
            <a href="#" data-index="{!i}" onclick="{!c.handleRemoveLeadAnchorClick}">
                Remove
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>{!lead.FirstName}</td>
        <td>{!lead.LastName}</td>
        <td>{!lead.Company}</td>
        <td>{!lead.Email}</td>
    </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

I've intentionally included a **ui:button** and a standard HTML **a** (anchor) to show how to get the index value in both cases. The controller actions are shown below.

```
({
    handleRemoveLeadButtonClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var self = this;  // safe reference

        var domEvent = event.getParams().domEvent;
        var bodySpan = domEvent.target.nextSibling;
        var index = bodySpan.dataset.index;
        helper.removeLead(component, index);
    },
    handleRemoveLeadAnchorClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var self = this;  // safe reference

        var index = event.target.dataset.index;
        helper.removeLead(component, index);
    }
)}
```

And `helper.removeLead()` is defined as follows:

```
({
    removeLead : function(component, index) {
        var leads = component.get("v.leads");
        leads.splice(index, 1);
        component.set("v.leads", leads);
    }
})
```

Comment: What if I'm using a checkbox to remove an item? I'm neither using an anchor nor a button in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I added a button in `expenseList.cmp` to handle removing of the expense item.

```
<ui:button label="Remove" press="{!c.remove}"/>
```

Then, I created an event, `deleteExpenseItem.evt`, to capture and pass the removed item.

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
 <aura:attribute name="expense" type="Expense__c"/>
</aura:event>
```

Fire the event in `expenseListController.js`.

```
remove: function(component, evt, helper) {
    var expense = component.get("v.expense");    
    var deleteEvent = $A.get("e.c:deleteExpenseItem");
    deleteEvent.setParams({ "expense": expense }).fire();
}
```

Handle the event in `form.cmp`.

```
<aura:handler event="c:deleteExpenseItem" action="{!c.deleteEvent}" />
```

Add the handler to `formController.js`.

```
deleteEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.deleteExpense(component, event.getParam("expense"));
}
```

Call your Apex controller to delete the expense item and update the view in `formHelper.js`.

```
deleteExpense : function(component, expense, callback) {

    var action = component.get("c.deleteExpense");
    var self = this;
    action.setParams({
        "expense": expense
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            //remove only the deleted expense from view
            var expenses = component.get("v.expenses");
            var items = [];
            for (i = 0; i < expenses.length; i++) {
                if(expenses[i]!==expense) {
                    items.push(expenses[i]);  
                }
            }
            component.set("v.expenses", items);
            self.updateTotal(component);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

And don't forget to include the delete DML operation in `ExpenseController.apxc`.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Expense__c deleteExpense(Expense__c expense) {
    delete expense;
    return expense;
}
```

Comment: This is incredible for such a simple operation. The effect is the same as if you accessed the element and called a .remove on it. Why wouldn't there be a .remove? I can dynamically create and add components why can't I also remove them in a very simple manner especially if I have a reference to the component I created dynamically in the first place. This is insane complexity for things that are so simple.