# Multiple input inside aura:iteration table

Tags: lightning, aura, aura-iteration

I have an attribute that I am rendering to a table inside an aura:iteration with the following code:

```
<aura:attribute name="licenceassocparties" type="String[]" default="false" access="PRIVATE"/>

<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--striped slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal"
        role="grid">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
            Name
        </th>
        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
            Role
        </th>
        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
            Email
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <aura:iteration var="party" items="{!v.licenceassocparties}">
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Name">
                <div class="">{!party.name}</div>
            </td>
            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Role">
                <div class="" data-label="Role">{!party.role}</div>
            </td>
            <td role="gridcell" class="" data-label="Email Address">
                <div class="" data-label="Email Address">
                    <ui:inputEmail class="field"
                                   maxlength="80"
                                   mouseout="{!c.addEmails}"
                                   placeholder="Email Address"/>
                    <span id="{!'emailInput'+index}"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The 3rd column is an email input field and I would like to capture the input for each row (if it's not null, which is a valid option) and pass this data to the controller for processing.
I based the below controller class on this solution ([HERE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108244/lightning-component-retrieve-values-from-dynamic-forms)) but I am getting 'undefined' for variable 'val'.

```
addEmails : function(component,event,helper) {
    var targetCmp = event.getSource();
    var val = targetCmp.get('v.value');
    console.log(val);
    var inputId = targetCmp.getElement().nextSibling.nextSibling.id;
    console.log(value);
    console.log(inputId);
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of retrieving multiple inputs from a dynamic table such as this? Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

To add further clarity of what I'm trying to achieve, the screenshot below shows a table with multiple email input fields (there can be a variable number of rows in this table, depending on the data source). What I would like to do is get any input email values (if they are not null) and add them to the correct element/position of the "licenceassocparties" array.

[image]

Comment: Try adding aura:id and then access the elements with `cmp.find('id')` this will return the element or an array of elements, use this for further checks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you are trying to achieve by this component.
But Quick fix to your problem i.e getting undefined value would be to add value attribute to ui:inputEmail component.

You can keep default value as blank or some value as

```
<ui:inputEmail class="field" maxlength="80" mouseout="{!c.addEmails}" placeholder="Email Address" value="some value"/>
```

OR

You can assign attribute to value

```
<ui:inputEmail class="field" maxlength="80" mouseout="{!c.addEmails}" placeholder="Email Address" value="{!v.attribute}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. To explain better what I'm trying to achieve, I've added further info to the question. I don't think it's as simple as adding a static value to the component as the input is rendered inside of an iteration (with a variable number of rows).

Comment: By adding value as blank tag I was able to get I was able to get value in   targetCmp.get('v.value');
    console.log(val);

Comment: @nom - Could you please let us know the solution for this problem? I am kind of stuck in a similar situation.