# I can't get index of the row in a aura:iteration component in the client side controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, datatable, summer-16, locker-service

In my lightning component, I have a table with column that has a menu in it. The menu items are for edit and delete. I'm trying to find a way to get the row that was clicked on and so far everything thing I've found/tried hasn't worked. This is in a Summer 16 sandbox w/Locker Service enabled.

These approaches no longer work:

- [How to remove items from a dynamic list in Lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55310/how-to-remove-items-from-a-dynamic-list-in-lightning-component)
- http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2016/01/freezing-users-with-lightning-components.html

Here is the top level component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId">
<c:AffiliationsList curRecordId="{!v.recordId}" />
<c:AffiliationDetails />
```

Here is the component that has the datagrid:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" controller="AffiliationController">
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS103/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.min.css"/>

<aura:attribute name="curRecordId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="afList" type="AffiliationWrapper[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="numAf" type="Integer" default="0"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:affiliationToEdit"/>

<div class="slds">
    <div class="slds-card">
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                    <c:svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-contact slds-icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#contact"/>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-truncate">Affiliations ({!v.numAf})</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Relationship
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Relationship</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Status
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Status</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Project
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Project</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Sub-Project
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sub-Project</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Task
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Task</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Notes
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Notes</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-cell-shrink"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.afList}" var="af" indexVar="idx">
                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent slds-has-flexi-truncate" id="{!idx}">
                            <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Relationship">{!af.relationship}</td>
                            <td class="slds-truncate" data-label="Status">{!af.status}</td>
                            <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Project">
                                <a >{!af.project}</a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Sub-Project">{!af.subProject}</td>
                            <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Task">{!af.task}</td>
                            <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Notes">{!af.note}</td>
                            <td class="slds-cell-shrink" data-label="Actions">
                                <ui:button aura:id="edit" label="Edit" press="{!c.editAffiliation}"/>
                                <!-- <ui:menu>
                                    <ui:menuTriggerLink aura:id="trigger" title="more"/>
                                    <ui:menuList class="actionMenu" aura:id="actionMenu">
                                        <ui:actionMenuItem aura:id="edit" label="Edit" click="{!c.editAffiliation}"/>
                                        <ui:actionMenuItem aura:id="delete" label="Delete" click="{!c.deleteAffiliation}"/>
                                    </ui:menuList>
                                </ui:menu> -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.loadAffiliations(component, event);
    },
    editAffiliation : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.editRecord(component, event);
    }
})
```

Here is the helper:

```
({
    loadAffiliations : function(cmp, ev) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.getAffiliations");
        action.setParams({
            "currentId": cmp.get("v.curRecordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var affiliations = response.getReturnValue();
                cmp.set('v.numAf', affiliations.length);
                cmp.set('v.afList', affiliations);
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('errors', response.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    editRecord : function(cmp, ev) {
        var row = cmp.getEvent("editAffiliation");
        console.log('row', row);
    }
})
```

`console.log('row', row);` logs out as `null`.

Originally my approach was just to pull the indexVar and then I'd be set but that's when I started finding out that none of the old ways worked anymore.

In my function, I'm thinking I should be able to get the value via `getSource()` on the event, but so far I haven't been able to figure out what, if any, key holds that value. It seems there should be a way to get to the `dataset`. Is there anyway to get the value for `data-index` from the event? It appears that the Locker Service has blocked everything. Or is there another approach that would work better? Any suggestions?

Comment: Try deleting rows using **Event** mechanism,check out my [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/121672/20830)

Comment: @Praveen That doesn't appear to work... logs out as null `editRecord : function(cmp, ev) {
        var row = cmp.getEvent("editAffiliation");
  console.log('row', row);
 }`

Comment: Please post enough code by editing your question,so that i can help you out.

Comment: There really isn't anything to post other than my controller method editAffiliation which just calls the helper editRecord method which is what I pasted above. `editAffiliation : function(component, event, helper) {
  helper.editRecord(component, event);
 }`  I was just starting on this part of the functionality and ran into the issue of not being able to identify which row to edit.

Comment: No need to include the apex controller,just post your component,it's controller.js and helper.js and also Lightning Event (.evt) file alone.

Comment: It's not possible to debug the issue,with the code you have posted now.Please don't post it as comment,post the code by editting your question

Comment: if you are not familiar with **Events**,this trailhead [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lightning_components/lightning_components_events_handle) will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest patch, we can now get to the element with `event.srcElement` so that solves my issue. I'm setting the id equal to the index and that's exactly what I was after!

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="{!idx}" onclick="{!c.editAffiliation}">Edit</a>

editAffiliation : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.editRecord(component, event);
}

editRecord : function(cmp, ev) {
    var afList = cmp.get('v.afList');
    var affiliation = afList[ev.srcElement.id];
    this.openModal(affiliation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Event driven mechanism is probably the right way to handle this,instead of relying on the `dataset` attributes on the DOM.Inorder to do so,you have to split the component into two parts:

1.AffiliationsList  - (fetches the data) -> Parent Component

2.AffiliationsListItem - (displays each record,fires selected data for edit) -> Child component

**AffiliationsList.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" controller="AffiliationController">
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS103/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.min.css"/>

<aura:attribute name="curRecordId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="afList" type="AffiliationWrapper[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="numAf" type="Integer" default="0"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:handler name="appEvent" event="c:affiliationToEdit" action="{!c.editAffiliation}" />

<div class="slds">
    <div class="slds-card">
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                    <c:svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-contact slds-icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#contact"/>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-truncate">Affiliations ({!v.numAf})</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Relationship
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Relationship</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Status
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Status</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Project
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Project</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Sub-Project
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sub-Project</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Task
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Task</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Notes
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                                    <c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS103/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Notes</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-cell-shrink"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.afList}" var="af" indexVar="idx">
                        <c:AffiliationsListItem afRec="{!v.af}"
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</aura:component/>
```

**AffiliationsListController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.loadAffiliations(component, event);
    },
    editAffiliation : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.editRecord(component,event);
    }
})
```

**AffiliationsListHelper.js**

```
({
    loadAffiliations : function(cmp, ev) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.getAffiliations");
        action.setParams({
            "currentId": cmp.get("v.curRecordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var affiliations = response.getReturnValue();
                cmp.set('v.numAf', affiliations.length);
                cmp.set('v.afList', affiliations);
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('errors', response.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    editRecord : function(cmp, ev) {
        var row = event.getParam("selectedAffliation");
        console.log('row', row);
    }
})
```

*Assuming your component level event looks like this :*

**affiliationToEdit.evt**

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Affiliation To Edit Event">
    <aura:attribute name="selectedAffliation" type="Object"/>
</aura:event>
```

**AffiliationsListItem.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="afRec" type="Object"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:affiliationToEdit"/>

    <tr class="slds-hint-parent slds-has-flexi-truncate">
        <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Relationship">{!v.afRec.relationship}</td>
        <td class="slds-truncate" data-label="Status">{!v.afRec.status}</td>
        <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Project">
            <a >{!v.afRec.project}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Sub-Project">{!v.afRec.subProject}</td>
        <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Task">{!v.afRec.task}</td>
        <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Notes">{!v.afRec.note}</td>
        <td class="slds-cell-shrink" data-label="Actions">
            <ui:button aura:id="edit" label="Edit" press="{!c.editAffiliationRecord}"/>
            <!-- <ui:menu>
            <ui:menuTriggerLink aura:id="trigger" title="more"/>
            <ui:menuList class="actionMenu" aura:id="actionMenu">
            <ui:actionMenuItem aura:id="edit" label="Edit" click="{!c.editAffiliation}"/>
            <ui:actionMenuItem aura:id="delete" label="Delete" click="{!c.deleteAffiliation}"/>
            </ui:menuList>
            </ui:menu> -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</aura:component>
```

**AffiliationsListItemController.js**

```
({  //Fires the event to the parent,to capture the selected affliation record.
    editAffiliationRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        var event = component.getEvent("appEvent");
        event.setParams({
            'selectedAffliation':component.get("v.afRec")
        });
        event.fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveen  Does the nested component support sorting on the table? I was planning to use sortable or Tablesorter so that's why I steered away from this approach.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the sortable in a nested component

Comment: I think your listItem component can fire a 'sort' event with parameter "asc" or "desc". The list component can handle that event and sort the afList array. This will rerender all the items in the list and display in sorted order.

Comment: @prashanthkr that might work...  thanks for the idea!